# JQuery - very simple script runs but breaks page

Tags: jquery

I'm attempting to run a very simple jQuery script after loading the jQuery library. I've used multiple paths to the library in an attempt to fix this issue, but from what I can tell, the library is loading just fine; the jQuery script runs, but breaks my [simple] webpage in the process.

Here is a simplified version of my webpage, excluding any unrelated markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>  
</head>
<body>

    <script>
        $("body").text("jQuery works");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run this, the text "jQuery works" displays successfully, but in the meantime the entire page breaks into repeating strips:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/ESykpmT.png]

And before the script:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/TIv80Ng.png]

Thanks for the quick responses guys, and again, a apologize for the beginner mistake. As usual, the StackOverflow community has shown to be extremely fast-acting and very helpful. Thank you all.

Comment: You're replacing all of the DOM within the `BODY` element with the text node "jQuery works". It's unclear what you want to do with the text, but if you simply want to append it, you can write `$("body").append("jQuery works");`

Comment: Let me edit - In this example, I've removed the rest of the elements for readability.

Comment: Looks fine to me. That repeating strip is the background of your website, and you replaced all body content with "jQuery works"

Comment: This feels like standing on one leg and kicking it with the other...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line of code:

```
$("body").text("jQuery works");
```

Should be changed to

```
$("body").append("jQuery works");
```

That will just write the text to the body instead of replacing the entire contents.

The reason it runs as just strips is because the height drops to just a handful of pixels high, which causes the background image to repeat

Comment: Nice! Thanks, easy fix for a beginner mistake. Having to use jQuery for the first time to install a mobile-enabled feature. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You are replacing the body content with the words "jQuery works", which is being displayed on a repeating background.

I suggest you read into what `.text()` actually does. http://api.jquery.com/text/

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks! (New to JQuery altogether)

Answer (score 2):

As crush notes in the comment above, you're replacing the entire $('body') contents rather than appending to them or alerting in some manner.

Answer (score 1):

the `text()` method will remove all contents of the body and replace it with that text. Without seeing your markup, I would guess that is not what you intend to do.

Comment: Thank you! I figured it would be a simple fix. I'm unfortunately only just beginning jQuery. Newbie mistake!

Comment: I appreciate the quick answer!